# How to handle iteration of dictionary in Antlr StringTemplate?

Tags: c#, dictionary, stringtemplate

How do you handle iteration over a C# dictionary in StringTemplate4 ?

```
<td style="padding-left:6px">
  $order.Extra : {ext | 
    $ext.Key$ : $ext.Value$ }$
</td>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dictionaryExample(order) ::= <<
<td style="padding-left:6px">
 $order.Extra.keys : {k | 
  $k$ : $order.Extra.(k)$ }$
</td>
>>
```

Is this what you're looking for? Iterate over the keys and apply the key to the dictionary when you want the value associated with it.

Output:

```
<td style="padding-left:6px">
   key1 : value1
   key2 : value2
   key3 : value3
</td>
```